# Calling service from Html

Tags: html, webservices-client

i want to call asp.net web service from java script and pass the parameters to it .is there any code sample or demostration  that will help me to acheive that?? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below link is a pretty decent method from my experience.

http://encosia.com/2008/03/27/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Answer (score 2):

JQuery:

```
function AddLocation(ParentID) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../server.asmx/Save",
        data: "{'ID':'0','ParentID':'" + ParentID + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            var item = document.createElement('option');
            item.value = data.d.split("$")[0];
            item.text = name;
            //do stuff
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery supports this behavior. you can use jQuery to do the ajax call as show below. this method has two call back functions for success and for failure.

```
function loadData()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'methodurl',
        success: methodSuccedded,
        error: methodFailure
    });
}

function methodSuccedded()
{
    //do your logic.
}

function methodFailure()
{
    //do your logic.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do so, using AJAX, and get the response from the server as an JSON object.

```
    var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp");
    var url = "Service1.svc/ajaxEndpoint/";
    url = url + "Sum2Integers";
    var body = '{"n1":';
    body = body + document.getElementById("num1").value + ',"n2":';
    body = body + document.getElementById("num2").value + '}';

    // Send the HTTP request
    xmlHttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xmlHttp.send(body);

    // Create result handler 
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange= function X()
    {

         if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
         {
              result.innerText = xmlHttp.responseText;
         }
    }
```

Getting the response as JSON would help you evualte it asn object and u can act on it through JavaScript.

See these links for reference:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alikl/archive/2008/02/18/how-to-consume-wcf-using-ajax-without-asp-net.aspx

http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/ajax/JSON-EnabledWCFServicesInASPNET35.aspx